# Sitecore data in Fact_AutomationStates table and AutomationStates MongoDB collection is out of sync

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a CD and CM servers as a production environment with Sitecore 8.0 + EXM 3.1.2 installed.

When I look at Engagement Plan Monitor I see some conflicts in the data: the Pie Chart numbers are out of sync with the data you get when hit the View Users button on particular state.

After small investigation I figured out that data for the View Users report is taken from MongoDB "AutomationStates" collection whereas the Pie Chart takes it's data from SQL reporting "Fact_AutomationStates" table. In fact these two data sources are out of sync.

Does anyone faced similar problem?